# Allow chaining in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, chaining

it's been a long day and I can't seem to figure out why one of my custom jQuery plugins won't chain.

What i'm trying to do is write a line of characters out one at a time in an element then when done remove the text then write the next line

The plugin:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.writeDialogue = function(content) {
    var contentArray = content.split(""),
      current = 0,
      elem = this,
      write = setInterval(function() {
        if(current < contentArray.length) {
            elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
        } else {
          clearInterval(write);
          return this;
        }
      }, 100);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Pretty much i'm trying to chain it in this way:

```
$('#element').writeDialogue(textLine1).empty().writeDialogue(textLine2);
```

Can't get it to work, any ideas?

Comment: U need  to return this so it returns an instance of the jquery function. so after the setInterval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your code is async. so you have to move `return this`:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.writeDialogue = function(content) {
    var contentArray = content.split(""),
      current = 0,
      elem = this,
      write = setInterval(function() {
        if(current < contentArray.length) {
            elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
        } else {
          clearInterval(write);
        }
      }, 100);
      return this; // THERE
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Just to follow up, how do I get the code to queue, if I run it in the example above (chained) it will try to write both out at the same time...

Comment: you'd need to add a done callback for it after your clearInterval I would imagine

Comment: can someone tell me why this chaining required and what exactly chaining do??